# unable to insert data into wordpress db using form

Tags: php, insert, wordpress

When i click on **submit** it doesn't create new posts in the posttype. It just refreshes the page.The below is a pagetemplate assigned to page.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert( 'contacts', array('post_title'=>$_POST['name'],'email'=>$_POST['email']));
    }
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="name" id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
<button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `name attribute` in your form element

```
<input type="name" id="inputName" name="name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email">
<button type="submit" name ="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the HTML

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" name="name">
<input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" name="email">
<button type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: yes...contacts is the name of posttype tht i wantto create the post in

Answer (score -1):

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" name="username">
<input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" name="useremail">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert( 'contacts', array('post_title'=>$_POST['username'],'email'=>$_POST['useremail']));} ?>
```

Now Check. I think it's working properly.

Comment: if not then please check the form is submit with their value or not. add var_dump($_POST); after if condition while the form is submitted. if the value is there. please same, assign query in a variable and set var_dump (); for query. it's return true, then ok... else false if the query is wrong.

Comment: i get array (size=3) 'username' => string 'test' (length=4) 'useremail' => string 'test@123.c0m' (length=12) 'submit' => string '' (length=0)

Comment: if i do if($wpdb->insert....){ var_dump($_POST)} then i do not get the data dumped on the screen

Comment: Hello @iamrockstar please add var_dump($_POST); in between if(isset($_POST['submit'])). like this.
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
var_dump($_POST);
} ?>